# Call the content of a file inside a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am a beginner in React Native Expo and I am looking for a way to publish the content of a file inside this function:

```
function HomeScreen() {
    return (
      // Here
    );
}
```

How can I do this?

I tried various combinations of code and tried looking in the official code for the createBottomTabNavigator function:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator

but there doesn't seem to be anything similar. They only show the functions that I also have in the actual code.

This is the complete file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { Home } from './screens/home';
import { Archivio } from './screens/archivio';
import { Sfide } from './screens/sfide';
import { Profilo } from './screens/profilo';


function HomeScreen() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home!</Text>
      </View>
    );
}

function ArchivioScreen() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Archivio!</Text>
      </View>
    );
}

function SfideScreen() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Sfide!</Text>
      </View>
    );
}
  
function ProfiloScreen() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Profilo!</Text>
      </View>
    );
}
  
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator
          screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
              let iconName;
  
              if (route.name === 'Home') {
                iconName = focused
                  ? 'home'
                  : 'home-outline';
              } else if (route.name === 'Archivio') {
                iconName = focused ? 'grid' : 'grid-outline';
              } else if (route.name === 'Sfide') {
                iconName = focused ? 'flame' : 'flame-outline';
              } else if (route.name === 'Profilo') {
                iconName = focused ? 'person-circle' : 'person-circle-outline';
              }
  
              // You can return any component that you like here!
              return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
            },
          })}
          tabBarOptions={{
            activeTintColor: '#E26DA0',
            inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
          }}
        >
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Archivio" component={ArchivioScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Sfide" component={SfideScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Profilo" component={ProfiloScreen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
```

Thanks to those who can help me and sorry for the stupid question but I'm just starting out.

Answer (score 0):

First import the file into the one where you want to render it.

```
import myFunctionalComponent from "./components/path to component"
```

Render with:

```
<myFunctionalComponent />

// Or

<myFunctionalComponent> </myFunctionalComponent>
```

Also make sure you export the functional component as you make it.

```
export function myFunction() {}

// or add 

export default myFunction

// to the bottom of the file
```

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I made a stupid mistake and imported by putting {}. Could you explain me what is the difference between "import { Home } from './screens/home';" and "import Home from './screens/home';"?

Comment: This should help explain: https://javascript.info/import-export